# Cannot find view : NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, html, django, django-urls

I am new to python and django and I am working on a project which is already build and I am just learning to understand it by adding some new views.

Application uses TemplateViews and I created a view which is just like the other views created. The Url pattern is also kind of same to the urls which are working fine. But my new page I created is not working and is giving me the error.

Working urls:

urls.py:

**

```
url(r'^aboutxyz/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="aboutxyz.html"), name='about_xyz'),
url(r'^contactus/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="contactus.html"), name='contact_us'),
```

**

base.html:

**

```
<li><a href="{% url 'about_xyz' %}">About XYZ</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'contact_us' %}">Contact Us</a></li>
```

**

These 2 pages are working fine. But when I add this:

urls.py:

**`url(r'^aboutxyzsg/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="aboutxyzsg.html"), name='about_xyz_sg'),`**

base.html:

"`<li><a href="{% url 'about_xyz_sg' %}">About XYZ sg</a></li>`"

Here is the code from urls.py file which contains url_patterns:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),  # grappelli URLS
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    '',

    # zinnia-tinymce
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    url(r'^tinymce/zinnia/', include('zinnia_tinymce.urls')),

    # index (home)
    url(r'^$', Index.as_view(), name="main_page"),

    # all-auth account
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

    # custom user
    url(r'^accounts/', include('users.urls')),

    # Privacy Policy
    url(r'^privacypolicy/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="privacypolicy.html"), name='privacy_policy'),

    # About XYZ
    url(r'^contactus/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="contactus.html"), name='contact_us'),
    url(r'^aboutxyz/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="aboutxyz.html"), name='about_xyz'),
    url(r'^aboutxyzsg/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="aboutxyzsg.html"), name='about_xyz_sg'),

)
```

It is not working and giving me error:

My error log shows:
"NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'about_xyz_sg' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []"

Please help me I am in deep trouble

P.S. - I tried putting **aboutxyzsg** url pattern before **aboutxyz** and still same error

Comment: The new url pattern is it added to the existing urls.py, or have you created a new one?

Comment: in the existing url patterns

Comment: Something is not right with you application setup, as the error says `0 patterns tried`. Since, you already have some patterns this shouldn't have been the case

Comment: But the project was working fine until I add this new url and add html into base.html file

Comment: Did you save the file, and restart the server?

Comment: I didnot restarted the server. Actually I am accessing the code using FTP and I dont have the entire code on my laptop . So could you tell me how can I restart my server in this case

Comment: Is the server running a web server (Apache, NginX etc) or the development server? In the former, you should restart the web server itself and/or the WSGI server (if any).